# What's another way to say something has happened prematurely?

Tags: phrase-requests

I’m trying to write a bit in a story that’s describing a person who has weather beaten clothes that have been rapidly aged by salt water, but for the life of me, I can’t remember the fitting or commonly used word or phrase to describe it.

It’s close to the word *prematurely,* but with implications of it having happened at a faster than normal, accelerated pace, before its time, in an expedited manner, or much sooner than it would have under normal conditions, basically.

Comment: Are you searching for a phrase, or a word? Our help for [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) and [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) is available to help formulate questions to get good answers. An example sentence with a blank in it is always useful.